# How to get Spotify music list without Authentication

Tags: flutter, spotify, libspotify, spotify-app

I want to know about, is it possible to Fetch a Spotify music list without an Access token or Aothuentication in mobile flutter SDK or web API. because I want to only Fetch the Spotify music list in my flutter app.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Spotify API requires app authentication or user authentication depending on the ressource.

Playlists are always associated with an user and require a valid Access Token (which means user authentication). See the playlists documentation [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#category-playlists).

> Both Public and Private playlists belonging to any user are retrievable on provision of a valid access token.

On the other hand, [albums](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#category-albums) for example can be retrieved with just the app credentials and do not require an authenticated user.

Comment: App Credential and authenticate user maybe both are same.

Comment: No. App credential are the App ID and the App secrets that you get when creating an app on your Spotify Developer account. An access token is what you get once an user authenticates with Spotify through your app.
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/